# Running operations over two different DataSets on the same Job fail with CorruptConfigurationException due to local class incompatible

Tags: scala, dataset, apache-flink

I'm writing a Flink Job in Scala, with two DataSets, as follows:

```
val latsDS : DataSet[String] = {
  env.fromCollection(lats.values.toSeq)
}
val entsDS : DataSet[Seq[Entity]] = {
  env.fromCollection(ents.values.map(l => l.asScala))
}
```

Then, later on I do:

```
val ec = entsDS.map( x => x.length ).map((_,1)).groupBy(0).sum(1)
ec.writeAsCsv(path,"\n","-",WriteMode.OVERWRITE)
env.execute
```

That works perfectly, as expected.

If I do instead of the above:

```
val wc = latsDS.flatMap(_.toLowerCase.split("\\W+").filter(_.nonEmpty).map((_,1)))
.groupBy(0).sum(1)
wc.writeAsText(path2,WriteMode.OVERWRITE)
env.execute
```

That also works perfectly. But, if I write instead:

```
val wc = latDS.flatMap(_.toLowerCase.split("\\W+").filter(_.nonEmpty).map((_,1)))
.groupBy(0).sum(1)
wc.writeAsText(path2,WriteMode.OVERWRITE)
val ec = entitiesDS.map( x => x.length ).map((_,1)).groupBy(0).sum(1)
ec.writeAsCsv(path,"\n","-",WriteMode.OVERWRITE)
env.execute
```

I get `Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: com.testflink.mywordcount.WordCount$$anon$4; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -8230073325803923865, local class serialVersionUID = -4336418598811571750`

A more complete stack trace follows.

```
   Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Call to registerInputOutput() of invokable failed
            at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:505)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The initialization of the DataSource's outputs caused an error: Could not read the user code wrapper: com.testflink.mywordcount.WordCount$$anon$4; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -8230073325803923865, local class serialVersionUID = -4336418598811571750
            at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.DataSourceTask.registerInputOutput(DataSourceTask.java:89)
            at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:502)
            ... 1 more
    Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.util.CorruptConfigurationException: Could not read the user code wrapper: com.testflink.mywordcount.WordCount$$anon$4; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -8230073325803923865, local class serialVersionUID = -4336418598811571750
            at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.util.TaskConfig.getStubWrapper(TaskConfig.java:286)
            at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.instantiateUserCode(BatchTask.java:1420)
            at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.chaining.SynchronousChainedCombineDriver.setup(SynchronousChainedCombineDriver.java:90)
            at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.chaining.ChainedDriver.setup(ChainedDriver.java:77)
            at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.initOutputs(BatchTask.java:1291)
            at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.DataSourceTask.initOutputs(DataSourceTask.java:284)
            at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.DataSourceTask.registerInputOutput(DataSourceTask.java:86)
            ... 2 more
    Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: com.testflink.mywordcount.WordCount$$anon$4; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -8230073325803923865, local class serialVersionUID = -4336418598811571750
            at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:616)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1623)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
            at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:287)
            at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.readObjectFromConfig(InstantiationUtil.java:245)
            at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.util.TaskConfig.getStubWrapper(TaskConfig.java:282)
            ... 8 more
```

Comment: The problem might be cause by the fact that you are running two independent data flows (both parts are not connected by a binary operator such as `join`, `coGroup`, or `union`) with a single `execute` call. Is there a reason why you do not run each program independently? Anyways, I agree that this problem calls for some investigation.

Comment: @FabianHueske I did ec.union(wc) (fixing wc's type first to match) and it's failing in the same manner. The reason I did that is that I will need to operate over various datasets and am building incrementally.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem but I didn't succeed. I replaced `Entity` by `String` because I don't know this type. How do you execute your job? Do you start the job from an IDE or do you submit it to a cluster? Does the failure occurs after the first job submission or only after the first try? Which version of Flink are you using? Could you compile a complete Flink job which produces your problem and post it here? Could you maybe share the logs of the TaskManager on debug level with us?

Comment: @TillRohrmann I'm using 1.0-SNAPSHOT, Commit ID: d9a061c (compiled from github sources). The failure happens always, I'm doing flink run myjob.jar on a three node cluster. I changed to a DataSet[Seq[String]] as well and I could reproduce, so Entity seems not to be related. I did a quick try to set logs in DEBUG level (changed root level on log4j.properties and logback.xml) but didn't work out, still got only INFO level traces. Tomorrow I'll look deeper into the logging issue and prepare a simple autocontained sample.

Comment: I think you have to restart the server to take the new logging level if you haven't already done it.

Comment: @TillRohrmann I couldn't find the way to get DEBUG logs on the TaskManager (set every rootLogger config to DEBUG, restarted everything). But, stranger of all, I started trying to generate a test case and I actually made it work, without changing a thing!. I pasted the whole code from the failing project on a new project and it now works... :? If I ever find the cause (naming? corruption of compiled code?) I'll ping you back... If you are interested in digging deeper, you can contact me at vinkoid on Twitter.

Comment: Good to hear :-) Let me know in case you encounter the problem another time.

Comment: I wonder if setting a fixed `serialVersionUID` for the functions fixes the issue?